# Every time I try to build a simple "hello world" I always get 2 errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm using visual studio 2010.

Every time I try to build a simple "hello world" I always get 2 errors.

Here's the code::

```
#include  <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 int main ()
 {
  cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
 }
```

> Error 2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\hershell
>   kurt\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\test\Release\test.exe  test
>
> Error 1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   _WinMain@16   C:\Users\hershell kurt\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\test\test\MSVCRT.lib(crtexew.obj)  test

How do I fix this?

Comment: It's actually single error; first line just informs you that you have unresolved external, next is *the error line* - there is one unresolved external, thus one linker error.

Answer (score 2):

Strange, I just created an empty project and pasted your code and it works fine for me.

Make sure you created your project as `Win32 Console Application`, then in the window that appears click next and select "empty project".

Comment: TY to all ,
thx so much men.

i run it with no error

now every time that i will do a proj do i need to do this all the time.?

i mean using the win32 console will be my default setting and not use the empty
 proj..

^^ i just want to clarify if theres an error in future using win32 console and an empty proj.

Comment: @ningpta: Well if you want just a simple console application you should use Win32 Console Application every time. That's it.

Comment: @ningpra BTW, don't forget to mark the most useful answer as accepted for future readers to find it quickly.

Answer (score 2):

> You have created Win32 project and there is no "main" function, but WinMain. Google it or use "win32 console application". as [Alanir Alonedaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/927209/alanir-alonedaw) and [Tudor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/808486/tudor) stated; Try and create a new project but select console application instead of win32 project.

It should compile correctly after this :)

A win32 project requires a "WinMain" function as opposed to the "main" function required by a console application. A win32 project is typically a GUI based application based on the Windows API

Comment: TY to all ,
thx so much men.

i run it with no error

now every time that i will do a proj do i need to do this all the time.?

i mean using the win32 console will be my default setting and not use the empty
 proj..

^^ i just want to clarify if theres an error in future using win32 console and an empty proj.

Answer (score 1):

You have created Win32 project and there is no "main" function, but WinMain. Google it or use "win32 console application".

Comment: TY to all ,
thx so much men.

i run it with no error

now every time that i will do a proj do i need to do this all the time.?

i mean using the win32 console will be my default setting and not use the empty
 proj..

^^ i just want to clarify if theres an error in future using win32 console and an empty proj.